# Vue (Webpack): Refreshing / editing embed element mounted by vue

Tags: webpack, vue.js, embed

I have a component which takes a string, in this case the initials of a cryptocurrency coin and use an npm package ('cryptowatch-embed') to get and mount a live chart embed from Bitfinex onto the document.

My issue is that the first time the component is 'activated' it works fine. But whenever I want to change it I have to edit the original chart object which is:

```
let chart = new CryptowatchEmbed('bitfinex', this.coin.toLowerCase() + 'usd', {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100%'
})
```

I can change the object's values like so:

```
chart.currencyPair = coin.toLowerCase() + 'usd'
```

And do `chart.mount('#chart-container')`

But that adds another instance of the chart to the document, so I need to either update or replace it somehow but currently I have no Idea how to do that, at least purely with Vue.

Any ideas?

Comment: It's unlikely that the embed is intended to be updated. You will need to destroy the existing one and create a new one when things update.

Comment: @RoyJ Yes, probably not intended for Single Page Applications. But how do I destroy and reinitialize it?

Comment: If you re-assign `chart` to a `new CryptowatchEmbed`, the old one should get garbage-collected. You may also have to clear the `innerHTML` of `#chart-container`.